# How to trigger custom button by REST API call

Tags: apex, api, rest

I'm trying to achieve the following but can't seem to find a way to get it to work.

On a custom Salesforce object, there is a custom button present in the UI. Clicking on this button triggers an action.

I would like to trigger this button/action from a REST API call, so that I don't need to open the Salesforce UI to do this.

I can retrieve a Bearer token to access the Salesforce API.

I have found/tried the following.

- Inspecting the button in Chrome Developer tools gives me an 'apiname' value, but no idea where to use this.
- The button is a 'Detail Page Button', with Content Source 'URL' and the following code (renamed some variables)
  `{!URLFOR( $Site.BaseUrl + "/apex/XYZ", null, [id = Service.Id, action='actionNameHere'])}`
- Clicking on the button opens a new tab within Salesforce with some results. These results are not relevant for me so are not needed.

I have looked at the Salesforce Rest API documentation as well as the Postman collection available, but haven't found any calls that appear to do what I need.

I'm not a Salesforce developer, but we're developing automations where part of the automation is happening in Salesforce. Thus we are trying to find the most ideal solution to our problem.
So I also don't have knowledge about the underlying action that happens when clicking the button, and the Salesforce developers at this company are understaffed.

Comment: Take a look at the docs on [URLFOR](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_urlfor.htm&type=5) - if you understand how it works, you'll be able to build the URL manually and make the call via REST.  Value of `Service.Id` will have to be available/known to your REST client, think about how you'll acquire that. (Please don't reply in comments - edit your question or post a new question).

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].. Please edit your post to include details about the action itself.  If it is a Visualforce page, you won't be able to call it from the API - you'll have to write some custom Apex to act as a REST API endpoint.

Comment: @DavidCheng I added some information, I'm no Salesforce developer so no idea if it is a Visualforce page. How would I write custom Apex to act as a REST API endpoint?

Comment: That URLFOR is opening a VF page which is most likely associated with a custom VF Controller. The URLFOR is also passing two parameters which either the VF controller is reading and/or the VF page is reading an operating on. You can't really invoke VF from an API

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem to be the best option for you. If you want to trigger the action the button triggers, but from outside Salesforce, you should have the code that the button is firing exposed as a web service (that is: available for HTTP calls from outside the platform).

In your case the button seems to be redirecting you to a custom Visualforce page. The page most likely has an Apex controller that does something. This "something" is what you will want to expose as a service.

There is a lot more things involved in this kind of thing, such as your own ability to store and secure your Salesforce credentials locally (so you can get the session token without opening the UI, as you mentioned).

You mentioned that you are not a developer, so it might be a good idea to hire one to do this for you (perhaps even a consultancy, so they can properly review this requirement against your actual code base and determine the best solution).